# React- Issue with infinite loop in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a useEffect() that fetches the data through axios, I want that to render only one time so I passed an array. Everything works fine, but the problem is whenever I try to sort the items, the second useEffect fires just followed by the first useEffect, which is causing the component to fetch the items all over again and again.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      return await axios
        .get('/getAllProducts')
        .then((response) => {
          setProducts(response.data);
          console.log(products);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [products]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you passed an array containing your `products` state, rather than an empty array, which will fire `useEffect` on state change (for `products` state specifically). Try changing your code to an empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
const getProducts = async () => {
  return await axios
    .get('/getAllProducts')
    .then((response) => {
      setProducts(response.data);
      console.log(products);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  };
  getProducts();
  }, []);
```

As @skyboyer mentioned below, it is good to note that state is not updated in a synchronous manner. Therefor, `console.log(products)` will not reflect an accurate value for your state when `useEffect` runs.

It is okay to use multiple `useEffect` hooks. If you would like to view your updated state in the console, or do some other work with it, you could add another `useEffect` hook and pass your state into the array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(products);
}, [products]);
```

Comment: ...and also remove `console.log(products)` to satisfy ESlint as well as not outputting previous value for `products` which does not make any sense

Comment: i think it wants to see the result data from the product state after making a call from axios, so it should create a new useEffect separate from the call to see the data change..
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(products);
}, [products]);

Answer (score 1):

Since `products` is in the `useEffect` dependency array, it is going to run every time there are changes made to the `products` state. `getProducts()` runs `setProducts` which then in turn is going to trigger the use effect again. Using an empty array in the `useEffect` will tell it to only run when the component is mounted.

Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const getProducts = async () => {
  return await axios
    .get('/getAllProducts')
    .then((response) => {
      setProducts(response.data);
      console.log(products);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  };
  getProducts();
  }, []);
```

Comment: How does your answer contribute to the topic additionally than a previously posted answer?