# Promise All causes Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, promise

I am trying to fetch an array of urls and using Promise.all for this. That works properly. However I need to show the data in UI and thus I am using useState hook. But setState ( setLocationResidents(results) ) causes an infinite loop. How can I fix this ?

Below is my code

```
const residentsUrl = [
'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/10', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/81', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/208', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/226', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/340', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/362', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/375', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/382', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/395'
]

const [locationResidents, setLocationResidents] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchAll() {
    const results = await Promise.all(
      residentsUrl?.map((url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json()))
    );
    console.log("results", results);
    setLocationResidents(results);
  }
  fetchAll();
}, [residentsUrl, locationResidents]);

 <div>
      {locationResidents
        ?.map((location) => (
          <div>{location.name}</div>
        ))}
 </div>
```

Comment: Remove `locationResidents` from the dependency array for `useEffect`. It doesn't need to be in there and is causing the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React- Issue with infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70246816/react-issue-with-infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

Comment: thanks all, that worked. but also i needed to remove residentsUrl as well. i think both causes this mistake. loop stopped when dependency is empty @henry woody

Comment: Well `residentsUrl` actually should be in there but, you're right that it'll cause an infinite loop the way it's currently defined. If you don't plan on modifying its value at all you can define `residentsUrl` outside the component and omit it from the dependency array. If you are going to change it, then put it in a state variable or something and include it in the dep array for `useEffect`.

Comment: ahhh very cool, didnt know that. so actually i went with the second way because i have to use it inside of my component. thus i changed to "const [urlChange, setUrlChange] = useState(residentsUrl);" and used urlChange in dep array and it worked. but can you also explain why this is working like that ? why do we have to put residentsUrl in a state variable ? @henry wood

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove `locationResidents` from useEffect watchers. It's causing useEffect to re-run every time `locationResidents` changes.